# reinterpret_cast on pointers pitfall between char and unsigned char?

Tags: c++, char, uuid, reinterpret-cast, unsigned-char

I'm using the following function in order to create an UUID and write it in a human-readable form into a pre-allocated buffer. Something goes wrong.

```
void createUUID(char* pDst)
{
    UUID    lUUIDObj;
    UuidCreate(&lUUIDObj);
    unsigned char*  lDest = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pDst);
    UuidToStringA(&lUUIDObj, &lDest)
}
```

At the end of the method, the debugger says:

- lDest = 0x01fe4fd8 "df4a5ed8-c0d2-495a-84d7-ce0e07cf2113"
- pDst = 0x0012ec7c "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"

I thought that both would have the same content, however it is not the case.

**What happened?** Thanks.

Comment: Are you debugging an optimised build? That will probably not bother to preserve `pDst` across the final function call, since it's not needed after the assignment to `lDest`. What happens if you step out of the function, and look at the result from the caller's viewpoint?

Comment: Absolutely not, this is a debug build (/MDd), and once returned, the value in my buffer is also ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `UuidToStringA`, it says:

> The RPC run-time library allocates memory for the string returned in the StringUuid parameter.

This means that after the call `lDest` does no longer point to `pDst`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void createUUID(char* pDst)
{
    UUID    lUUIDObj;
    UuidCreate(&lUUIDObj);
    unsigned char*  lDest = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pDst);
    //UuidToStringA(&lUUIDObj, &lDest);
    UuidToStringA(&lUUIDObj, lDest);
}
```

Looks like you clobbered the *value* of `lDest` without changing the values it originally *pointed to*.

Comment: I should have read the pointer value, at least I would have found that it was changing in the UuidToStringA call.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete [Joachim Pileborg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893835/54956), here is the corrected function:

```
void createUUID(char* pDst)
{
    UUID    lUUIDObj;
    UuidCreate(&lUUIDObj);
    unsigned char*  lTmpStr;
    UuidToStringA(&lUUIDObj, &lTmpStr);
    sprintf(pDst, reinterpret_cast<char*>(lTmpStr));
    RpcStringFreeA(&lTmpStr);
}
```